# Store "multiple" Stateful and Stateless Widgets in one dart file. Is it okay?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm slightly new to Flutter and just want to ask some questions/clarifications regarding the development using it. I am currently building a flutter app and wanted to change the layout based on different devices and orientations. I created 2 different dart files containing different app layouts of my Login page (**LoginMobile.dart** and **LoginTablet.dart** respectively). I created also a separate dart file (LoginComponents.dart) to store "all" the object UI/components of my login form (txtEmail, txtPassword, btnLogin, etc.). I heard doing like `Widget txtEmail() {return TextformField(...);}` is not advisable as it can affect the app performance, so I tried making them as classes. Am I doing it right? Is it okay to store multiple stateful widgets in one dart file(?) since the txtPassword have a setState() for show/reveal password and the btnLogin for the authentication process. Is there any negative effects that I may face in the long run if I continue doing it this way? Any tips and advise were highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Storing your widgets in a single file is okay but would cause confusion when making a large app. when the amount of widgets is getting increased in that file it would be harder to do a small change because its harder to find the widget.

i would recommend using multiple files, so you can find them and organize them easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But point comes to maintainability. I prefer to keep one public widget which having the same name as the filename and remaining private widgets.

So now ques is How many widgets in a single file?

Its actually depend there is no such rule to restrict the limit of file. Different authors having  different preference. I prefer try to keep 5-6 classes(widgets) and
each one having 5-6 functions.

- Try to make a file single responsible i.e(5-6 classes together responsible for single functionality). Don't make god class which having unrelated concerns together later it will pains(haha)
- If it's a common widget keep them separate to respect DRY principle(Don't repeat yourself)
- If the widget is further divided into 3-4 widgets or it children widget change depend upon rest response keep seprate for good practise
- Bonus Tip: try using code folding shortcuts to push a little more